# jquery imagesLoaded plugin: how to listen to every image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using imagesLoaded plugin to trigger some actions when all the images are loaded. But now I want to do something after every individual image is loaded, is it doable using imagesLoaded plugin?

Comment: /* edited */ Take a look at batchImageLoad plugin. It's lightweight and has the 'loadingCompleteCallback' to use everytime an image is loaded (it does the magic based on img tags). Link: http://www.yankov.us/#Projects